# Better looking Bootstrap Data Tables

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

HI I would like to achieve better looking bootstrap data tables that are more attractive to users. Is there a bootstrap library I can use to achive this?  am currently using the latest bootstrap.

Comment: Are you referring to [tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/) using the [bootstrap3](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html) theme?

Comment: Hi. Am referring to the latest twitter bootstrap.

Comment: You can try the datatables theme creator.https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator

Answer (score 0):

Try adding classes to the table tag:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>value</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables for more examples.

For added functionality, I recommend https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html# which easily integrates search, number of rows shown at a time, and re-ordering of columns (personally, I haven't gotten the re-order to work yet, but the rest is fine).

Answer (score 0):

Try Bootstrap Table

*An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)*

http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/